# SQL Select Query Sorted Value

Tags: mysql, sql

OK Now I have this table named Game

```
Player     Score      TimesPlayed
  1         900           5
  2         500           3
  3         350           2
  4         600           4
```

I need a Query to return the Score multiplied by the number of TimesPlayed of each Player sorted in descending order. So I need this as output

```
4500 - Player 1
2400 - Player 4
1500 - Player 2
700  - Player 3
```

I had written this, but don't know if its the right way to go.

```
SELECT Score, Player, TimesPlayed FROM Game ORDER BY Score DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the score multiplied, you need to multiply...

```
SELECT Player, Score * TimesPlayed as total_score FROM Game ORDER BY total_score DESC
```